# An example of a non first countable Fréchet-Urysohn space?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, examples-counterexamples

As the head title says, I need a Fréchet-Urysohn space but not first countable, (on the way, a good Text book to follow).
Thanks.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/281289/8348).

Comment: The example mentioned by Arthur Fischer is also mentioned in Engelking's General topology in Examples 1.4.17 and 1.6.18. This book has a chapter devoted to Fréchet-Urysohn and sequential spaces, which is fairly detailed.

Comment: You also asked about a good textbook for general topology. You can already find several question on this site about this topic, see the section on topology in [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions).

Comment: Dan Ma has on his blog a series of posts on sequential spaces, [starting here](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/sequential-spaces-i/). He includes examples showing that none of the implications fist countable $\Rightarrow$ Fréchet $\Rightarrow$ sequential $\Rightarrow$ k-space cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Another example which has not been mentioned so far:

Let $(X,\tau)$ denote the real line with the cofinite topology. The uncountability prevents $X$ from being first-countable.

What about convergence? We can distinguish three cases:

- If $(x_n)_n$ assumes no value infinitely often, then it converges to **every** point in $X$.
- If $(x_n)_n$ assumes exactly one value infinitely often, then it converges to this point and no other point.
- If $(x_n)_n$ assumes several values infinitely often, then it diverges.

The result is an immediate consequence of
**Lemma:** Let $x\in X$ and $(x_n)_n$ a sequence in $X$. Then $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ if and only if for every $y\ne x$ we have $x_n=y$ for only finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$.

It is now easy to prove that $(X,\tau)$ is Fréchet-Urysohn.

Comment: Of course any uncountable set will do in place of the real line. Your example is not a Hausdorff space but that is easily fixed by making all points but one isolated, e.g., use the topology $\tau=\{U\subseteq\mathbb R: 0\notin\mathbb R\vee|\mathbb R\setminus U|\lt\aleph_0\}$

Answer (score 1):

I am posting as a CW answer some things that have been mentioned it the comment. Feel free to edit it further.

Such example is given in Arthur Fischer's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/281289/).
The example mentioned by Arthur Fischer is also mentioned in Engelking's General topology in Examples 1.4.17 and 1.6.18. This book has a chapter devoted to Fréchet-Urysohn and sequential spaces, which is fairly detailed.

Dan Ma has on his blog a series of posts on sequential spaces, [starting here](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/06/21/sequential-spaces-i/). He includes examples showing that none of the implications fist countable $\Rightarrow$ Fréchet $\Rightarrow$ sequential $\Rightarrow$ k-space cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Question was changed to specify "not first countable."

An example is apparently constructed here: http://dml.cz/dmlcz/140083

(I didn't actually read this paper.)

Comment: Sorry, I edited the main question, I am looking for not first countable Fréchet-Urysohn space.

Comment: By "anything" did you mean "nothing"?

Comment: No.  For instance a manifold is Frechet-Urysohn.