# $X$ is a first-countable space and $A \subset X$, show $x \in \bar A \iff \exists (x_n) \rightarrow x$

Tags: general-topology

Here is the question:

> Let $A$ be a subset of a first-countable topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$. Prove that $x ∈ X$ is in the closure $\bar A$ if and only if there is a sequence $(x_n), x_n ∈ A$, which converges to $x$.

I can't seem to get a handle on proving either direction.

Comment: Concentrate for now on proving that if there is a sequence in $A$ converging to $x$, then $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$; that is true in any topological space, not just first countable ones, and the proof is a very straightforward application of the definitions of _limit of a sequence_ and _belongs to the closure of_ $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use $\overline{A} = \{x \in X: \forall O \in \mathcal{T}: x \in O \to O \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$, the closure is the set of adherent points.

If such a sequence exists then every open set that contains $x$, must contain a tail of the sequence, and thus contains points of $A$, hence $x \in \overline{A}$. No first countability needed yet.

If OTOH $x \in \overline{A}$, let $(U_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be a countable local base for $x$, using first countability. 
For each $n$ we pick $x_n \in (\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i) \cap A$, which can be done as the intersection is open (a finite intersection of open sets), contains $x$ and so intersects $A$ by $x$ being in $\overline{A}$. Now if $O$ is any open neighbourhood of $x$, some $U_N \subseteq O$ (local base!) and then all $x_n$ for $n \ge N$ are in $O$. So $x_n \to x$, and we have the required sequence.

Comment: Late late comment or rather a question . I know that if a space is not first countable then this converse you proved is not true. However I am struggling to come up with a simple example disproving it.  For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281267/if-a-in-mathrmclos-does-it-follow-that-there-exists-a-sequence-of-points . This post gives an example but uses quotient spaces which I have not yet done. But is there an easy example in something like cofinite topology which is not first countable?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron the cocountable topology on $\Bbb R$ that can be used to disprove the question in the lemma. It is indeed not first countable, but it’s not Hausdorff so the quotient space is a nicer example in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is easy.  If $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\to x$, then every nbhd $N$ of $x$ contains an $x_n$, hence $N\cap A\ne\emptyset$.  So $x\in \bar A$.

The other direction isn't much harder.  Take a countable nbhd base $N_k$ for each $x\in\bar A$.  Then for each $n$, there is $x_n\in \bigcap_{k=1}^nN_k\cap A$.  Then $x_n\in A$ and  $x_n\to x$.

Comment: Take the $N_n$ decreasing, or in increasing intersections.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok.  Will do.

Comment: @copper.hat suspected that was wrong.