# Continuous image of half-line is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I came across something in the literature a few weeks ago (without proof):

> If $X$ is a one-to-one continuous image of $[0,\infty)$, and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $X$ is metrizable.

How can you prove this?

EDIT: I originally left out the assumption that $X$ is a **one-to-one** image. You will need this!

Comment: The restriction is a homeomorphism on all $[0,n]$, e.g. by the compact and Hausdorff fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see $X$ does not even have to be sequential.

Let $u$ be any point in $\beta [0,\infty) \setminus[0,\infty)$ and let $X$ be
the quotient of the subspace $[0,\infty) \cup \{u\}$  identifying $u$ with $0$. Then $X$ is a Hausdorff space because $\{0, u\}$ is compact. The restriction of the quotient map to $[0,\infty)$ is a continuous bijection
onto $X$.

The interval $[1, \infty)$ is not closed in $X$: since $[0,1]$ is compact,
it is closed in $\beta[0,\infty)$, so $u$ must be a limit point of 
$(1,\infty)$.

However, $[1, \infty)$ is sequentially closed: it is closed in
$[0,\infty)$, which, because it is normal, is sequentially closed in its Čech-Stone compactification. ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35397/3457))

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have essentially given $[0,\infty)$ a coarser topology by enlarging the neighborhoods of $0$. Given a free ultrafilter $u$ on $\omega$, we can define a neighborhood of $0$ to be $[0,\epsilon)\cup \bigcup _{n\in A}(n,n+1)$ where $\epsilon>0$ and $A\in u$. The resulting space should be Hausdorff, but not first countable at $0$. Correct?

Comment: Or, given a sequence $s\in \omega^\omega$ we can define a neighborhood of $0$ to be $[0,\epsilon)\cup \bigcup _{n\in \omega}(s(n),s(n)+1)$ where $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Explicitly constructing a neighbourhood base from a free ultrafilter on the positive integers was my first approach. Then I thought that I might as well use a free z-ultrafilter on $[0,1)$ a.k.a. a point in $\beta[0,1)$, which already carries a suitable neighbourhood base. The final result is very similar.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Seeing that this claim appears to be incorrect, may I ask what literature you found it in? Just curious.

Comment: @M10687 It was an old paper (1960's maybe), I thought, but I haven't been able to find it again.  Maybe I'm imagining things.